Change of cursor has rendered system unstable
I have just updated to Ubuntu 22.04 and I am now having significant issues with graphics settings related to themes and cursors.  My first attempt to change themes resulted in the dreaded Oh no! Something has gone wrong. screen, which was only overcome by a complete reinstall.
While moving through options today without thinking I went to change cursors, and selected Redglass from the default.  All manner of badness has now cropped up.  The Oh no screen appears, but if I push enter it drops through to my desktop.  The red glass cursor is there, but when the cursor is over the side bar or top bar it changes to a white square.  I cannot open either Settings or Gnome-Tweaks to change the cursor back, these programmes start then immediately crash and shut down.
What's next?

OK, disabling the NVidia drivers and reverting to the XOrg ones allows me to run settings and tweaks again.  Still no closer to being able to reach my main goal, which was to install the Adapta theme.
